# Convert String "01-09-2015' to Long - Java/Android

Tags: java, android

Hi I have a String like this "01-09-2015"
I need to convert this string to long.

I have tried using

```
String date = "01-09-2015";
Long dateLong = Long.getLong(date);

Long dateLong = Long.valueOf(date);

Long dateLong = Long.valueOf(date,36);

Long dateLong = Long.parseLong(date);
```

Still no help. Everything returns be NumberFormatException.
Anyone please help.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Guys, I will send in a String, which is of course a date like "08-01-2015". For each unique string which I pass, I need a unique long value. Thats all.

Comment: What value do you expect? Because a leading zero isn't going to be storable in a `Long`.

Comment: I will need some unique value for each date which I convert. If date is same, same value should come. So unique value for unique strings I pass.

Comment: And what value would that be for `"01-09-2015"`?

Comment: I need some unique value.

Comment: Have you considered 20150109? What are you trying to do?

Comment: see my edit. U will understand.

Comment: `Everything returns be NumberFormatException` Because "08-01-2015" is **not** a valid number.

Comment: Thanks Franky. Nice to hear from you after a long time. Thats really a great invention you mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to convert it to Date first before changing it to Long

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
Date d = format.parse("01-09-2015");
long milliseconds = d.getTime();
```

Comment: That's in case the OP needed the milliseconds, it's not mentioned in the post.

Comment: @MouseEvent he mentioned in the comments that he just needs a unique value for each date. Milliseconds will satisfy this.

Comment: So it is okay to do just this: `long value = 1092015L`?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you split the input on `-`, then convert the three date parts to `int`; and then concatenate them into a `long`. Something like,

```
String date = "01-09-2015";
String[] arr = date.split("-");
int yyyy = Integer.valueOf(arr[2]);
int mm = Integer.valueOf(arr[0]);
int dd = Integer.valueOf(arr[1]);
long dateLong = (yyyy * 10000) + (mm * 100) + dd;
System.out.println(dateLong);
```

Output is (the unique, per date)

```
20150109
```

**Note** This is in keeping with [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601); the linked Wikipedia article says (in part)

> **ISO 8601** *Data elements and interchange formats – Information interchange – Representation of dates and times* is an international standard covering the exchange of date and time-related data.

Comment: The milliseconds conversion won't be unique ? Just a doubt.

Comment: You don't have a value for milliseconds; it'll be a lot of zeros. And a very large number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 (because that's epoch).